# Binding DataGrid and ObservableCollection in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I'm having a function that gets some 3 lists with strings inside. I've used ObservableCollection for keeping those 3 lists inside of it.

This is a definition of ObservableCollection:

```
public partial class CreateAreaDialogWindow : System.Windows.Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string, string>> _obsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string, string>>();

    }
```

After adding lists with method I've made I'm writing results in some DataGrid. Definition of DataGrid is like this:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="206" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,265,0,0" Name="tabela" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="556" SelectionChanged="tabela_SelectionChanged" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="Binding _obsCollection">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Item1}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MapTo" Binding="{Binding Item2}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Item3}"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Controller"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Service"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Injection"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Beside 3 lists of strings in 3 different columns I'm having 3 more columns with checkboxes. What is the problem is that I don't know how to do a binding in a proper way.
For example if I put this line in my code:

```
tabela.ItemsSource = _obsCollection;
```

I get 6 columns instead of 3, of course they have same content: 3 of those I get from XAML code (and binding in this case works) and 3 are from that line: `tabela.ItemsSource = _obsCollection;`

When I delete: `tabela.ItemsSource = _obsCollection;` I get an empty table with checkboxes.
So I know that the problem is in bad binding, but does someone has an idea how to edit this code so I can remove: `tabela.ItemsSource = _obsCollection;` and still get 3 columns with lists content and column headers: Type, MapTo and Name?

Comment: of course there are 6 columns.  You created 6 columns in XAML.

Comment: I meant 9 columns 6 of them with text and I've only needed 3 with text and 3 with checkboxes. Didn't told the story on a wright way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All  what you have to  is to set the `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` and create something like `MyViewModel` which will act  as your datacontext

try the following code:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();  
        }
    }
    public class MyViewModel

    {
          public MyViewModel()
          {
              for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
              {
                  _obsCollection.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>("Test" + i, "Test2" + i, "Test3" + i));   
              }
          }
        ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string, string>> _obsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string, string>>();

        public ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string, string>> MyObsCollection
        {
            get { return _obsCollection; }

        }
    }
```