# How to add new items to DataGrid without overwriting the old ones?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I know that there is no `Append`, but I believe that this is the proper way to call it (right?).

Right now I have an `ObservableCollection` which I use to add new items to my `DataGrid`. It works fine, but if I add 10 items once, and 15 items the second time I end up with 15 items, instead of 25. Basically the collection overwrites each collection over the old one.

I *could* loop through the old collection and add it again after I include the new collection, but that seems like very stupid thing to do. I am sure that there has to be another way to do that.

Here is what my class with the collection inside looks like ([I have used code from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21678326/1115382):

```
public class ProxiesList
{

    public string proxy { get; set; }
    public string proxySource { get; set; }
    public bool proxyUsed { get; set; }
    public bool toUse { get; set; }
    public string working { get; set; }

    ObservableCollection<ProxiesList> GridItems = new ObservableCollection<ProxiesList>();

    public ObservableCollection<ProxiesList> _GridItems
    {
        get
        {
            return GridItems;
        }
    }

    public void addTheData(MainWindow mw, List<string> proxyList)
    {
        foreach (string line in proxyList)
        {
            _GridItems.Add(new ProxiesList //add items to the collection
            {
                proxy = line.Split(';')[0],
                proxySource = line.Split(';')[1],
                proxyUsed = false,
                toUse = true,
                working = "n/a"
            });
        }

        mw.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = GridItems; //bind the collection to the dataGrid1

        GridItems = new ObservableCollection<ProxiesList>(); //create new instance of the observable collection

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.
So you just need to *append* your items to the same instance of your `ObservableCollection<ProxiesList>` which your datagrid is bound to.

So basically, you could either set `mw.dataGrid1.ItemsSource` to the `ObservableCollection<ProxiesList>` or use `Binding` in Xaml.

You don't need to set `mw.dataGrid1.ItemsSource` every time you're adding items.

```
GridItems = new ObservableCollection<ProxiesList>(); //create new instance of the observable collection
```

This line caused the your problem, because it creates a new instance of the collection, so every time you added your items into a new instance of the `ObservableCollection<ProxiesList>`, which means it only contains the items you just added.

So just remove the following lines from your `public void addTheData(MainWindow mw, List<string> proxyList)`

```
    mw.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = GridItems; //bind the collection to the dataGrid1

    GridItems = new ObservableCollection<ProxiesList>(); //create new instance of the observable collection
```

You could bind the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` in Xaml to your `_GridItems` property if your have `ProxiesList` set to your `DataContext`.

And other things like your property naming, it's better to follow the C# naming conventions.

Comment: Tried a few things - 1) I tried removing the first line, but nothing happens if I add to the `DataGrid` XAML - `ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems}"` or `ItemsSource="{Binding _GridItems}"`. 2) Removing only the second line does not seem to change my initial result (overwriting after each time I run it) 3) Removing both lines gets me the result from `1)`

Comment: if you just use `ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems}"` you need to keep an eye on your DataContext. you could simply set the `mw.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = GridItems;` like @har07 answered.

Comment: I finally got it. Solution was to bind the `ItemsSource` to the `DataGrid` in the app initialization. I have marked your answer as the solution because you answered first. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, there're several ways of binding the `ItemSource`. Usually, I do that in Xaml. I should have mentioned to you that you need to make the `DataContext` right. Bindings are widely used in `MVVM`, I bet you will like to have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

`ObservableCollection` has built in mechanism to notify UI (your `DataGrid` in this case) whenever item added to or removed from collection.

So it is enough to instantiate `ObservableCollection` and set `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` once. You can do that in constructor for example. The rest is simply add new items to existing collection :

```
public ProxiesList()
{
    GridItems = new ObservableCollection<ProxiesList>();
    mw.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = GridItems;
}

public void addTheData(MainWindow mw, List<string> proxyList)
{
    foreach (string line in proxyList)
    {
        GridItems.Add(new ProxiesList //add items to the collection
        {
            proxy = line.Split(';')[0],
            proxySource = line.Split(';')[1],
            proxyUsed = false,
            toUse = true,
            working = "n/a"
        });
    }
}
```

... and I don't see benefit of keeping `_GridItems` here, so you can remove it.

Comment: Now it doesn't add anything to the `DataGrid` and the loop binds the `ItemsSource` on every single cycle. For testing purposes I moved the code out from the loop and nothing changed - nothing gets added in the `DataGrid` and every time I try to add an item the `ProxyList()` gets called and re-binds the `ItemsSource`. Is there another way (instead of using a constructor)?